# Ok if a guitar sound is out of phase with the rest of the song?

Tags: mixing, daw, logic-pro, mastering

I designed a sound for a clean guitar. At first it was in phase, which sounded OK, but when I flipped the phase I liked that sound more. The Correlation Meter (in Logic) shows that the phase is now negative. All other parts of the song are in positive phase.

Is it OK to be out of phase (for production) if the instrument which is out of phase sounds good after this action, or should everything be perfectly in phase?

[image: correlation meter]

Comment: This is really an extension of https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/85128/panning-distorted-guitars-get-the-attack-sound If you flip the phase of one side of an identical stereo image, then in stereo it will sound like it's coming from "outside your head" in some strange ethereal way. In mono, it will vanish completely... hence my last comment on there "did you check it in mono?"

Comment: Check your mono compatibility by listening in mono, and/or with a stereo correlation meter. There are tools for fixing phase issues, for example Voxengo PHA-979 Phase Alignment Plugin https://www.voxengo.com/product/pha979/

Comment: @Tetsujin It doesn't vanish when converted to mono. Phase is flipped. That means... stereo image has some center material (sides did vanish, in fact). Looking at the correlation meter, it's perfectly in phase. In stereo I've got a cool effect and in mono it still can be heard clearly. That means? BTW sorry for no answering on previous thread, I thought it wasn't a question.

Comment: I have no knowledge of the Logic correlation meter, so the images don't help me. i think i'm down to "I need to hear it". Original & flipped versions. Overall, I'm probably safer leaving this to a Logic user.

Comment: There’s a lot I don’t understand here. What did you do to “design” the sound? Did you record a clean guitar track? And then you flipped the polarity? Did you record anything else at the same time as the guitar? Polarity and phase only matter if there’s another track with identical or similar content on it with a different phase or opposite polarity.

Comment: @ToddWilcox DI recording → Processing → Polarity flip. Sorry for bad knowledge, I guess.

Comment: If you phase-flip one mono instrument, no-one will ever know & no meter can ever tell either. Phase flipping only becomes 'dangerous' when it loses coherence with other tracks, ie in a left/right scenario if the overall pan would be central.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it sounds "better" then that's all that matters.  Your audience isn't critiquing some measurement deep in your signal chain, any more than it's analyzing your musical notation or your precompositional cocktail-napkin scribbles.

If you're worried that you're breaking a rule, plenty of musicians -- both composers and performers -- have pulled off stunts that scandalized their immediate teachers, but delighted audiences for the succeeding decades and centuries.

Be bold!